# Query union, if search result is less than 10, fill with others from database order by date

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make a mysql union search. My purpose is: my total results back must be 10.

- if search results are more than 10, the returned data come all from search result.
- if search results are less than 10, first few returned data come from search result, and then fetch the remaining results from database order by date.

To make it clearer: if a client searches "today", my database only returns 7 results which contain "today", then add another 3 results from my database ORDER BY date. So that the total results are 10 items.

Another purpose: another 3 results are not repetitions from the 7 results which match the search. I think `UNION` or `UNION DISTINCT` can do that job, am I right?

So, how do I do a query like this?

PS: my code will fix the result order, but I need first `select` is always behind the second `select`

```
(SELECT * FROM table WHERE title like %$searchword% limit 0,10 ORDER BY date)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM table limit 0,10 ORDER BY date)
limit 0,10 ORDER BY date
```

Comment: What's the condition behind the remaining results to be fetched in order to reach 10?

Comment: @Damien Pirsy, as I write in `To make it clearer:` , if search result return 7 items, then I want fetched other 3 result just order by date from database, so that my total results always are 10. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always want 10 results:

```
SELECT 
    IF(m.id,1,0) AS has_match,
    t.*
FROM 
    `table` t
    LEFT JOIN `table` m ON m.id = t.id AND m.title LIKE '%$searchword%'
GROUP BY t.id
ORDER BY has_match DESC, date
LIMIT 10
```

Tested:

```
mysql> select * from `table`;
+----+------------------------+---------------------+
| id | title                  | date                |
+----+------------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | test 1                 | 2011-11-06 10:27:08 |
|  2 | test 2 match           | 2011-11-06 10:27:14 |
|  3 | 3 match this too       | 2011-11-06 10:27:23 |
|  4 | title does NOT         | 2011-11-06 10:27:44 |
|  5 | Another matching title | 2011-11-06 10:27:55 |
|  6 | this does not either   | 2011-11-06 10:29:22 |
|  7 | Do not put this first  | 2011-11-06 10:29:37 |
|  8 | Is this number 8?      | 2011-11-06 10:29:57 |
|  9 | The 9th is a match     | 2011-11-06 10:30:07 |
| 10 | 10th does not          | 2011-11-06 10:30:20 |
| 11 | 11th IS a match too!   | 2011-11-06 10:30:37 |
| 12 | 12th gets ignored?     | 2011-11-06 10:30:49 |
+----+------------------------+---------------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT IF(m.id,1,0) AS has_match, t.* FROM `table` t LEFT JOIN `table` m ON m.id = t.id AND m.title LIKE '%match%' GROUP BY t.id ORDER BY has_match DESC, date LIMIT 10;
+-----------+----+------------------------+---------------------+
| has_match | id | title                  | date                |
+-----------+----+------------------------+---------------------+
|         1 |  2 | test 2 match           | 2011-11-06 10:27:14 |
|         1 |  3 | 3 match this too       | 2011-11-06 10:27:23 |
|         1 |  5 | Another matching title | 2011-11-06 10:27:55 |
|         1 |  9 | The 9th is a match     | 2011-11-06 10:30:07 |
|         1 | 11 | 11th IS a match too!   | 2011-11-06 10:30:37 |
|         0 |  1 | test 1                 | 2011-11-06 10:27:08 |
|         0 |  4 | title does NOT         | 2011-11-06 10:27:44 |
|         0 |  6 | this does not either   | 2011-11-06 10:29:22 |
|         0 |  7 | Do not put this first  | 2011-11-06 10:29:37 |
|         0 |  8 | Is this number 8?      | 2011-11-06 10:29:57 |
+-----------+----+------------------------+---------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: it looks a great query. I have only one table. so `m` is equal as `table`, but what is `t`?  Thanks.

Comment: Both are aliases of the same table, BUT you can think of m as the subset of rows that match since the on clause is limiting it to that.